# How can I export to a vsproject on my mac (C++)?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio, compilation, clion

I am a student with a Mac, my school requires I send in vsproject's (Visual Studio) for my homework.
I have **XCode** and **CLion** as my two **C++** IDE's I tried to export the CLion cmake file generated for VS but that wont work without the compiler (I think thats why it didn't work).
I do have the new **VS for Mac** but that wont compile anything in C++ atm (at least I don't know how too).
I am really hoping someone was able to figure this out by now cause its driving me nuts and really getting on my nerves, any help would be great.
*(I hope this is the right place to ask this sort of question too...)*
**EDIT:** To clarify:  I am using only basic std namespace in iostream, I do understand the issues as to why it might not work being OSX is Unix based and Windows is DOS based but I am hoping there is some way to get it done.

Comment: _it didn't work_ is not a useful problem description. Please describe **exactly** what's not working.

Comment: the problem is that MAC OS is basicly a Linux (but not quite) to some degree.  It is quite possible that your code even  _won't_  compile in VS, unless it only uses a C++ standard  library and nothing else (even POSIX headers may be problem, e.g. it's dup() on MAc and _dup()  in VS, thanks to ISO C++ conformity). If you need create something that is compilable in VS, you should create nmake's makefile (not same makefile as yours) by hand. That can be imported to VS. VS for MAc is not compatible with Windows VS and works ONLY with CLR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this using CMake. CMake Depends heavily on VS to generate `vsproject` files. (And likewise, you can't generate an `xcodeproj` on Windows because it depends on Xcode.)

However, there is another build system that is able to cross-generate these called [Gyp](https://gyp.gsrc.io). It is not compatible with CMake files, but if your project isn't too large, you could migrate to Gyp where you can generate vsprojects while still developing on macOS.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I'm looking for thanks so much!